# Export the counts from multiple queries into a single CSV or Excel?

Tags: plsql, reporting

There is an excel report of counts that I create manually by running 12 queries from 1 database and about 12 queries from another database. I want to automate this report so that the results from all of these queries can be exported to the relevant rows of the CSV or Excel ( I would like the completed csv or excel report to be automated).I have limited sql skills so a detailed answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks much for the needed help!

Comment: Can you give examples of what your current queries look like? Also, what database are you using?

Comment: The queries are the counts for various periodic transactions of the business. The database is Oracle